# SQL: getting a "rolling" average when joining two tables

Tags: sql

I have two time series tables: TS_A and TS_B.

TS_A looks like this (header and 2 sample rows):

```
year,month,value
2017,1,10
2017,2,20
2017,3,30
```

TS_B looks like this (header and 2 sample rows):

```
year,month,label
2017,3,A
2017,4,B
```

I want to join the two tables into one result set, such that I get the average of `value` from TS_A for the last 12 months (if available - if not, use the months that are available), starting the count from the year and month combination on TS_A.

So, for example, this would be the result set in the case of the above tables:

```
year,month,avg,label
2017,3,A,15
2017,4,B,25
```

Any idea on how to write this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select b.*,
       (select sum(a.value)
        from a
        where a.year * 12 + a.month >= b.year * 12 + b.month - 11 and
              a.year * 12 + a.month <= b.year * 12 + b.month
from b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT b.year, b.month, label, AVG(value) value
FROM `project.dataset.ts_b` b
JOIN `project.dataset.ts_a` a
ON a.year * 12 + a.month BETWEEN 
  b.year * 12 + b.month - 12 AND b.year * 12 + b.month - 1
GROUP BY year, month, label
```

if to apply to to the data in your example - result will be

```
Row year    month   label   value    
1   2017    3       A       15.0     
2   2017    4       B       20.0
```